# Adding Controls to a Bing Map Webpart for SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, alternate-access-mapping, ajax

I am using this WebPart to display Bing Maps, I did lots of research to find out, how can I put controls on it as one shown in picture in link but didn;t find any hint except AJAX might help, can anyone just give me hint to what should I search for to get what i want please.

My version of Map
[image: My version of Map]

Desired Map

[image: Desired Map (Controls in Blue background)]

[Here is the Code for Webpart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SP2010BingMapsWebPart.aspx)

Comment: didn;t let put third url so here it is [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SP2010BingMapsWebPart.aspx]

Comment: just find out, what i want is bing map SDK, and it has built in Ajax controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later On I find the answer to use Latest Bing Map API/SDK is the best option, here is the link

[Bing Map SDK](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7)